# Iterate through System.Drawing.Color struct and use it to create System.Drawing.Pen

Tags: c#, struct

I would like to iterate through the System.Drawing.Color struct and use it to init a pen list.

I tried it like this, but the type of field is not Fitting:

```
colorList = new List<System.Drawing.Pen>();

        foreach (var field in typeof(System.Drawing.Color).GetFields())
        {
            if (field.FieldType.Name == "Color" && field.Name != null)
            {
                colorList.Add(new System.Drawing.Pen(field, (float)1));
            }
        }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: @mbeckish `Color` is a class with a lot of `static` properties, not an `enum`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Except for [`Color.Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.empty.aspx), they're properties, not fields:

```
var colorList = new List<System.Drawing.Pen>();

foreach (var prop in typeof(System.Drawing.Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
{
    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(System.Drawing.Color))
    {
        colorList.Add(new System.Drawing.Pen((System.Drawing.Color)prop.GetValue(null), 1f));
    }
}
```

This produces `Pen`s with 141 colors with the version I'm running, should correspond to the list at [Color Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color_properties.aspx). It does not return `Empty`, though it does have `Transparent`. Also, I changed from `(float)1` to `1f`. The `f` tells the compiler that's a `float` literal, more concisely than casting `1` to `float`.

Comment: I removed "Transparent" and "Zero". I have not checked but I hope that the order is somehow chosen to be very different at the beginning.

Comment: If you want to make the order is consistent and sensible, you can do something like `GetProperties(...).OrderBy(x => x.Name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to change this in your code:

colorList.Add(new System.Drawing.Pen((Color)field.GetValue(null), (float)1));

`field` is just a [FieldInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instance and this is what it really is (from MSDN) :

> Discovers the attributes of a field and provides access to field
>   metadata.

But what you need is to get `Color`s **instances not metadata**, you can do that with the following piece of code :

```
(Color)field.GetValue(null)
```